# Rotating an image Delphi XE7

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe7

I would like to make a car dashboard with Delphi. I inserted the back plane of a dashboard and a needle. I would like to set the origin of the needle in the center of the dashboard, and it turn in a certain angle. I'm still a beginner in Delphi, any help would be appreciated !! thank you

Comment: I'm assuming you're using Firemonkey?

Comment: Have you looked into the built-in rotation support in Firemonkey?

Comment: Yes, but I have a problem to define the centre of rotation !

Comment: Did you read the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.RotationCenter)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FireMonkey controls have [`RotationCenter`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.RotationCenter) and [`RotationAngle`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Controls.TControl.RotationAngle) properties.  Load your needle image into a [`TImage`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE7/en/FMX.Objects.TImage) component, position it over the dashboard and set its `RotationCenter`, then you can adjust the `RotationAngle` when needed.